# Getting the text from a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

```
private void SaveFile()
       {
           Stream myStream;
           SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

           saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
           saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
           saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

           if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
               {
                   rtb1.Text().get();
               }
           }
       }
```

I use this when trying to get the text of a richtextbox and save it but it always comes up with error, CS1955

Comment: Correction the code it not `rtb.Text().get();` its `rtb1.Text()` but still gives the same error

Comment: If you want to get the content of the RichTextBox, directly use the `rtb.Text` property, instead of `rtb.Text()`. It's a property, not a method.

Comment: [RichTextBox.SaveFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile?view=netcore-3.1) - [RichTextBox.LoadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Use the [Rtf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf) property if you want to save text along with formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to write a simple text file then you can use the File.WriteAllText command instead.

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.Filename, rtb1.Text);
}
```

You just need to specify the filename with path, and then the text, which in this case is rtb1.Text (no brackets!)